# How to make the horizontal scroll bar appear in a JScrollPane that contains a JTextPane component

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar, jscrollpane, jtextpane

I can't make the horizontal scrollbar appear. I've tried using JTextPane.setSize(), JTextPane.setPreferredSize() and no size method for JTextPane. I'm also using JScrollPane.setPreferredSize().

The vertical scroll bar appears, but the horizontal one doesn't.

Here is an example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {

    private int         textPaneWidth    = 500;
    private int         textPaneHeigth   = 200;
    private int         scrollPaneWidth  = 100;
    private int         scrollPaneHeigth = 100;
    private JTextPane   textPane;
    private JButton     button;
    private JFrame      frame;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test gui = new Test();
        gui.go();

    }

    private void go() {

        frame       = new JFrame("Test");
        button      = new JButton("button");
        textPane    = new JTextPane();
        scrollPane  = new JScrollPane(textPane, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        textPane.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, 12));

        // Sizes:
//        textPane.setSize(textPaneWidth, textPaneHeigth);                             // ???
//        textPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(textPaneWidth, textPaneHeigth));     // ???
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(scrollPaneWidth, scrollPaneHeigth));

        frame.add(button);
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
             textPane.setText("==================================================================== \n" + 
                         "==================================================================== \n" +
                         "==================================================================== \n" +
                         "==================================================================== \n" +
                         "==================================================================== \n");
        }

    }
}
```

When the button is pressed, the string is added to the JTextPane. There is vertical scrolling, but no horizontal scrolling.

This is what I'm seeing after pressing the button:

[image: no horizontal scrolling :(]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there enough text for the bottom line to not appear?  Conversely, are all five lines of `=` appearing?

Comment: @Xynariz added the image of what is happening to the question.

Comment: Thank you, writing answer now.

Comment: @jon clements, the logic used by individuals of this forum never cease to amaze me. Do you even look at the information in the link BEFORE you decide to delete the answer? Because of the possibility of a link becoming obsolete at some time in the future you delete an answer that contains detailed information about the problem and multiple potential solutions to the problem, thus depriving any individual who reads this posting the benefit of all that knowledge. I though the point of a forum was to spread information.

Comment: This work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931965/how-to-make-jtextpane-scroll-horizontally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you need to extend JTextPane to avoid wrapping

https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1210688

```
class JTextWrapPane extends JTextPane {

    boolean wrapState = true;
    JTextArea j = new JTextArea();

    JTextWrapPane() {
        super();
    }

    public JTextWrapPane(StyledDocument p_oSdLog) {
        super(p_oSdLog);
    }


    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
        return wrapState;
    }


    public void setLineWrap(boolean wrap) {
        wrapState = wrap;
    }


    public boolean getLineWrap(boolean wrap) {
        return wrapState;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
//  instead of  private JTextPane jtp = new JTextPane( sdLog );
    private JTextWrapPane jtp = new JTextWrapPane( sdLog );
//and set LineWrap = (false):
        jtp.setLineWrap(false);
```

Comment: super(p_oSdLog); is throwing exception: The Constructor Object(StyledDocument) is undefined

Comment: i can see it here, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html

Comment: Yeah im an idiot, forgot to extend JTextPane. I'm already using the extended class, but it's not working. Still the same results as using JTextPane.

Comment: have you tried setting the LineWrap to false using setLineWrap

Comment: it works with jtp.setLineWrap(false); !!! I'm using private JTextWrapPane jtp = new JTextWrapPane() instead of private JTextWrapPane jtp = new JTextWrapPane( sdLog ); can it be an issue?

Comment: i dont think there would be any issues, you can use it as you would have used JTextPane

Comment: @JCPedroza, this solution doesn't work when the line length is less than the width of the viewport. That is the background of the text pane is not painted properly. Check out my answer for a more complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of digging, I figured out the issue.

[`JTextPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) does not just display a document, rather, it displays a styled document.  To quote from the [java tutorials:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#document) "One JTextComponent subclass, JTextPane, requires that its document be a StyledDocument rather than merely a Document."

When you create a `JTextPane` with a default constructor, as you did, you automatically create a [`DefaultStyledDocument`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultStyledDocument.html).  From the [documentation for `DefaultStyledDocument`:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultStyledDocument.html)

> These style runs are mapped into a paragraph element structure (which may reside in some other structure).  The style runs break at paragraph boundaries since logical styles are assigned to paragraph boundaries.

This means that the `JTextPane` is actually doing the word wrap *for* you.  One solution would be to try using a [`JTextArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) instead.

EDIT, per comments:
Another solution could be to create your own [`StyledDocument`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html) (possibly by extending from [`AbstractDocument`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/AbstractDocument.html)), set it up how you want, and pass this to the `JTextPane` constructor.

Comment: The problem is that I need text area to support styled text, and JTextArea only supports plain text.

Comment: Would JEditorPane work?  (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html)  JEditorPane suppors many more styles than JTextArea.

Comment: It does work with JEditorPane! Why? JTextPane extends JEditorPane doesn't it? Is there a way to make it work with JTextPane?

Comment: @JCPedroza - `JEditorPane` is a more general case, `JTextPane` is a more specific case, and part of the extra stuff `JTextPane` adds is the word wrap.

You can see Camickr's answer for a text pane solution.

Answer (score 1):

Only vertical scrolling without scrollbars

```
progressTextArea = new JTextPane();

JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane()
{
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(300, 100);
    }

    public float getAlignmentX()
    {
        return LEFT_ALIGNMENT;
    }
};

scroller.getViewport().add(progressTextArea);
```