# How to make JTextPane scroll horizontally

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane, jtextpane

I have a `JTextPane`, when there are too many lines, a `vertical` scroll bar appears, but when a line is too long, instead of appearing a horizontal scroll bar, the line breaks into two lines, how to make the horizontal bar appear instead of breaking into two lines, my `jTextPane` is added like this:

```
JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextPane1);
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a `JTextPane` and not a `JTextArea`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, it's `JTextPane`

Comment: It's a little quirky, but take a look at [this example](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/no-wrap-text-pane/)

Comment: @MadProgrammer its ture but can i ask u one more question related to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As presented [here](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/no-wrap-text-pane/) by our very own Rob Camick, you could try using something like...

```
JTextPane tp = new JTextPane() {

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
        return getUI().getPreferredSize(this).width
                        <= getParent().getSize().width;
    }

};
```

Which will stop line/word wrapping

Comment: @MadProgrammer +1 but I'm think that `return getPreferredSize().width < getParent().getWidth();` with success / override ScrollableSizeHint

Comment: @mKorbel Of the solutions I've seen, I tend to prefer this one, but that's just me